# Play console app rejected. issue: Not a core feature

Tags: android-storage

My app require all files access permission for hiding files (images,videos,and audios) so i had fill permission declaration form. and they rejected my release.
how to resolve this issue? my app requires full access but play console not allow me for all files access.

**Hiding file is app's main feature.**

**How to answer this question ?**
Explain why your app can't make use of more privacy friendly best practices, such as the Storage Access Framework, or the Media Store API. Improving the performance of your app is not an acceptable reason

Comment: Which files does it hide? Why does it hide those files? Is hiding files the app's main feature?

Comment: yes hiding files is the app's main feature.

Comment: Have you tried addressing the question they asked? "Explain why your app can't make use of more privacy friendly best practices" They just want to know why you want additional permissions.